# How to convert a datetime to string in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm surprised not to be able to find this question here already.

I have a date time var and I want to convert it to a string so that I can append it to another string. I want it in a format that can be converted easily back to a date time.

How can I do this?

(I want the date part and the time part.)

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I got lots of hits too but they all seemed to be converting the other way. Or wanting something more complicated.

Comment: Type `Convert`, double-click to highlight, press Shift+F1... always first line of defense.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

The following query will get the current datetime and convert into string. with the following format 
`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss(24h)`

```
SELECT convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 120)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9341)
- [SQL Server Date Formats](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: I still can't get over the fact that you have to pass arbitrary numbers to get the right format

Comment: @cja I totally share your surprise. I want to provide a string, like *yyddss* to get the exact format I want. There's probably a technical or historical reason to this. But still - very surpriannoying.

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix but in your answer you are coding the months as minutes, yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss NOT yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

Comment: Though this is old, I just ran into this thread. When using `DateTimeOffSet`, be sure to adjust the `varchar` length to what you want your outcome to look like. For me, I didn't want the timezone so I had to use `SELECT convert(varchar(19), sysdatetimeoffset(), 120)`

Answer (score 37):

There are many different ways to [`convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) a `datetime` to a string. Here is one way:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(25), getdate(), 121)  – yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.mmm
```

See [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/9343)

Here is a website that has a list of all of the conversions:

[How to Format datetime & date in SQL Server](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/)

Answer (score 14):

In addition to the `CAST` and `CONVERT` functions in the previous answers, if you are using SQL Server 2012 and above you use the [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh213505.aspx) function to convert a `DATETIME` based type to a string.

To convert back, use the opposite `PARSE` or `TRYPARSE` functions.

The formatting styles are based on .NET (similar to the string formatting options of the ToString() method) and has the advantage of being culture aware. eg.

```
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME2 = SYSDATETIME();
DECLARE @StringResult1 NVARCHAR(100) = FORMAT(@DateTime, 'g') --without culture
DECLARE @StringResult2 NVARCHAR(100) = FORMAT(@DateTime, 'g', 'en-gb') 
SELECT @DateTime
SELECT @StringResult1, @StringResult2
SELECT PARSE(@StringResult1 AS DATETIME2)
SELECT PARSE(@StringResult2 AS DATETIME2 USING 'en-gb')
```

Results:

```
2015-06-17 06:20:09.1320951
6/17/2015 6:20 AM
17/06/2015 06:20
2015-06-17 06:20:00.0000000
2015-06-17 06:20:00.0000000
```

Comment: Am I missing something or is the OPs problem solved with FORMAT(<date var>, 'dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss') or whatever custom date format you need?!

Comment: @Grim you can do that as well. From the docs `The format argument must contain a valid .NET Framework format string, either as a standard format string (for example, "C" or "D"), or as a pattern of custom characters for dates and numeric values (for example, "MMMM DD, yyyy (dddd)")`

Comment: I think you're actually working too hard here.  SQL Server has implicit string equivalents for DATETIME2.  What you're actually doing here is utilizing the implicit conversion and then formatting the resulting string, not the datetime.

Comment: @JamieMarshall more or less. MSDN suggests: `Use the FORMAT function for locale-aware formatting of date/time and number values as strings. For general data type conversions, use CAST or CONVERT.`

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, @datetime, 103) --for UK Date format 'DD/MM/YYYY'
```

101 - US - MM/DD/YYYY

108 - Time - HH:MI:SS

112 - Date - YYYYMMDD

121 - ODBC - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FFF

20 - ODBC - YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS

Answer (score 10):

There are 3 different methods depending on what I is my requirement and which version I am using.

Here are the methods..

1) Using Convert

```
DECLARE @DateTime DATETIME = GETDATE();
--Using Convert
SELECT
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @DateTime,120) AS 'myDateTime'
    ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), @DateTime, 120) AS 'myDate'
    ,RIGHT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @DateTime, 120),8) AS 'myTime'
```

2) Using Cast (SQL Server 2008 and beyond)

```
SELECT
    CAST(@DateTime AS DATETIME2) AS 'myDateTime'
    ,CAST(@DateTime AS DATETIME2(3)) AS 'myDateTimeWithPrecision'
    ,CAST(@DateTime AS DATE) AS 'myDate'
    ,CAST(@DateTime AS TIME) AS 'myTime'
    ,CAST(@DateTime AS TIME(3)) AS 'myTimeWithPrecision'
```

3) Using Fixed-length character data type

```
DECLARE @myDateTime NVARCHAR(20) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @DateTime, 120);
DECLARE @myDate NVARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @DateTime, 120);

SELECT
    @myDateTime AS 'myDateTime'
    ,@myDate AS 'myDate'
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `convert` statement in Microsoft SQL Server to convert a date to a string. An example of the syntax used would be:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(20), getdate(), 120)
```

The above would return the current date and time in a string with the format of `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` in 24 hour clock.

You can change the number at the end of the statement to one of many which will change the returned strings format. A list of these codes can be found in the [CAST and CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) page in Microsoft Learn.

Answer (score 2):

Check CAST and CONVERT syntax of T-SQL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?

Answer (score 2):

Try below :

```
DECLARE @myDateTime DATETIME
SET @myDateTime = '2013-02-02'

-- Convert to string now
SELECT LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @myDateTime, 120), 10)
```

Comment: Good !!
Do we need to write LEFT as well ?

Comment: Takes 10 first chars, so if you do need it if you just want the date.

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered by a lot of people, but I feel like the simplest solution has been left out.

SQL SERVER (I believe its 2012+) has implicit string equivalents for DATETIME2 as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Look at the section on "Supported string literal formats for datetime2"

To answer the OPs question explicitly:

```
DECLARE @myVar NCHAR(32)
DECLARE @myDt DATETIME2
SELECT @myVar = @GETDATE()
SELECT @myDt = @myVar
PRINT(@myVar)
PRINT(@myDt)
```

output:

```
Jan 23 2019 12:24PM             
2019-01-23 12:24:00.0000000
```

Note:
 The first variable (`myVar`) is actually holding the value `'2019-01-23 12:24:00.0000000'` as well.  It just gets formatted to `Jan 23 2019 12:24PM` due to default formatting set for SQL SERVER that gets called on when you use `PRINT`.  Don't get tripped up here by that, the actual string in `(myVer)` = `'2019-01-23 12:24:00.0000000'`

Answer (score 1):

In the stored procedure for me works something like this.

`convert(varchar(10), StartingDate) AS 'StartingDate'`