# Convert a SQl DateTime field with hh mm ss

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am inserting a datetime field into my SQL database with a format of 2014-10-29 12:05:24.927

My interface needs to display this as 29/10/2014 12:05:24

my tsql statement is :

```
SELECT Convert(VARCHAR(20), MessageAudit.AuditDate, 120) As AuditDate FROM tableA
```

Which, produces yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss how, can i format the date portion of this to be dd/MM/yyyy?

Comment: Which sql server version are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a datetime to string in T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029860/how-to-convert-a-datetime-to-string-in-t-sql)

Comment: Why not just do this date formatting on your UI rather than returning it with a specific format from the db?

Comment: if your interface needs to display data in a specific format modify the interface to do that. sql deals with information; the format used to display the information is not something sql nedds/should be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pretty extensive list of date formats in sql server:

http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx

for your specific problem you could do:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), AuditDate, 103) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), AuditDate, 108) AS AuditDate
FROM tableA
```

Though this will return the date as a string/varchar - which has it's own set of issues.  You're really better off keeping the date in a date format and formatting it on the front end.  This will allow you (depending on how the date is displayed) to still be "date" sortable rather than string sortable.

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like:

```
declare @Date datetime
select @Date = cast('20141029 12:05:24.927' as datetime)

select convert(nvarchar(10), @Date, 103) + ' ' + convert(nvarchar(10), @Date, 108)
```

It will give you precisely `29/10/2014 12:05:24`

Answer (score 2):

Concatenate two format dd/mm/yy & hh:mm:ss
e.g

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103) + ' ' + 
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 108) AS [Date]
```

Answer (score 1):

As http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms187928.aspx, you have to specify `103` as the third parameter of the CONVERT() function.

```
SELECT Convert(VARCHAR(20), MessageAudit.AuditDate, 103) As AuditDate FROM tableA
```

Comment: FYI this will only provide the date portion of the datetime, unless i misintepreted OP wanted the date portion formatted dd/mm/yyyy but still with the time portion as well