# SQL Server: change column datatype from datetime2 to nvarchar, convert existing data simultaneously

Tags: sql, sql-server

Management would like to change a column in our database from `datetime2` to `nvarchar`, basically storing a string of the date rather than a date&time value. What is the best way to do this? The column already has data in it, so I need to change the data type as well as convert the existing values to text.

(I've already tried to push back on this, but they have their reasons that aren't super relevant here)

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029860/how-to-convert-a-datetime-to-string-in-t-sql

Comment: Would your managers support keeping the `DATETIME2` column and adding a calculated column to store the `VARCHAR`? Something like `ALTER TABLE foo ADD date_as_text AS FORMAT(date_as_date, 'D')`

Comment: *"Management would like to change a column in our DB from datetime2 to nvarchar, basically storing a string of the date rather than a datetime value. What is the best way to do this?"* The best thing to do is not do they say. Honestly, management are fools for asking you to do this. Don't store a date an an `nvarchar`. It doesn't have have Unicode characters, so the "n" is a waste of space and 20/04/2000 is not "**after**" 01/01/2019.

Comment: Why are *managers* coming up with technical implementation decisions?

Comment: (did you) tell them that a date time value could be formatted on demand but it is a pain in the bottom other way round.

Comment: Oh yes, I told them all kinds of things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Management is wrong.  Date/time values should be stored using proper data types.  In general, storing them as strings is not a best-practice.

However, you can easily do this.  In fact, you can simply do:

```
alter table t alter datecol nvarchar(255);
```

If you want the data in a particular format, then use `update` afterwards:

```
update t
    set datecol = convert(nvarchar(255), convert(datetime2, datecol), ?);
```

Note:  if you just want a way to get a "pretty" date out of the table, use a computed column:

```
alter table t add datecol_pretty as (convert(nvarchar(255), datecol, ?);
```

Where `?` is the conversion format you want.  (Or use `format()`.)

Comment: Probably makes sense to add a `PERSISTED` here. `CONVERT`  tends to not be too expensive, but probably better do it at the time of the data is written than when the whole table is being queried. I don't recommend `FORMAT`, it's a performance killer (especially if the column isn't persisted).