# PeopleSoft Query Manager Expression

Tags: sql-server, peoplesoft

Using Microsoft SQL Server, I'm trying to format A.CHECK_DT as mmddyyyy - with leading zeros, so january 11th of this year would look like: 01112019. 
Trouble is everything I try isn't coming out right. The closest I've come to altering the format is:

> CONCAT(MONTH((CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.CHECK_DT,101))),DAY((CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.CHECK_DT,101))),YEAR((CONVERT(CHAR(10),A.CHECK_DT,101))))

But that converts the date to 1182019, no leading zeros. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

This script will get you a format of MMDDYYYY

Replace(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(A.CHECK_DT AS DATE), 101),'/','')

(Expression Type = Character, Length 10)

Comment: More detail available http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx (which I found via https://stackoverflow.com/a/15029872/44862 ). Solution there appears to match your own.

Comment: Thanks - I will when I can.

Answer (score 1):

[edit] Comment below applies to Oracle Database, but it turns out this question is for Microsoft SQL Server. I am leaving the answer up in case it is useful for others who find this question via search.

> Assuming you are on oracle, try using an additional parameter on the
>   `TO_CHAR` function to tell it how you want to format the output.
>
> You can format the date using `TO_CHAR`. the syntax is something like
>   `TO_CHAR(YOURDATE,YOURFORMAT)`. And for your specific example, it
>   would be `TO_CHAR(A.CHECK_DT,'MMDDYYYY')`
>
> Here is a web page that shows this SQL as a working query:
>
> - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2c01/3
>
> Here are some good resources I found by searching for: `Oracle
>   TO_CHAR`:
>
> - https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php
> - http://psoug.org/definition/TO_CHAR.htm
> - http://www.dba-oracle.com/f_to_char_sql.htm
>
> And of course, there is always Oracle documentation (although it tends
>   to have fewer examples):
>
> - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm
> - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34510

Comment: Thanks for the comment - that particular code doesn't work, i get this error: A SQL error occurred. Please consult your system log for details.
Error in running query because of SQL Error, Code=8603, Message=[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Executing SQL directly; no cursor. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]'TO_CHAR' is not a recognized built-in function name. [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Sta (50,380)

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify what kind of database you are using. My solution was for Oracle. If you are using Microsoft SQL Server, then it will be different. I will add that tag to the question.

Comment: My apologies - I didn't realize what kind of database it was until late yesterday. I thought that clarifying that it was PeopleSoft Query Manager was helpful - but it really wasn't. My team mate had to tell me about the SQL server - and then I did research and was able to figure it out.